# Future Perfect in the Past

Tags: modal-verbs, future-in-past

Can I use *should have done* for the future just like *will have done*? For example:

> It should have been finished by next Monday.

Which basically means *It should be finished by next Monday* but with extra emphasis on the completion of the action.

Or should I stick to *be finished* and not get stupid ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise against *should have been finished*.

At best it implies that, despite what was planned, it will not be finished by next Monday.

Assuming that you mean to convey that *it* will likely be finished by next Monday, I would stick with *it should be finished by next Monday*.

Comment: Agreed. “Should have been” indicates that it was (and is) not (“I should have been at your dinner, but I was sick”). There really can be no case for “should have been finished [in the future]”.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes.

A couple of examples I have gotten from COCA are copied here from my post, [Should as Future Perfect Modal](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43312/should-as-future-perfect-modal), on the English Language Learners sister site.

> Glim's shoulders droop a bit. He looks over at me, " Nothing. You? " #
>   " Nothing, " I say, shaking my head. " Sorry, Serba. These aren't
>   responsible. Nor do they suggest any meaning or use. " # " I never
>   really expected they would. I only hoped.
>
> *Perhaps we'll learn more from the experiments **next week**.* **You *should*
>   have started your tests by then** as well. " And perhaps the
>   disrupters will no longer be necessary, she sends. I shrug. Hope seems
>   far away, given Madrin's position. She is, after all, a telepist; her
>   opinion carries the weight of the Interplanetary Department of Justice
>   behind it.

```
Date: 1996
Publication information: June 96, Vol. 90 Issue 6, p129, 32p
Title: Communion.
Author: Gross, Gordon
Source: Fantasy & Science Fiction
```

Another quote is this:

> When you have seen the student regularly, you may need to take steps
>   to break dependency. It may be helpful to bring the issue into the
>   open and agree that this session ought to be the last. It is always
>   possible for the student to make another appointment if they really
>   feel they need it.
>
> The **next** interview may be more productive if you make it clear what
>   work or thinking the **student *should* have completed by then**.

```
Managing Teaching and Learning in Further and Higher Education
Kate Ashcroft, Lorraine Foreman-Peck
Psychology Press, 1994
```